# Group order from the orbit size in a faithful action.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, permutations

If we have a group $G$ acting faithfully on a set of size n, could we say the size of the group is at most $n!$? If so, why?

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FaithfulGroupAction.html - in the case of a faithful action $G$ can be identified with a subgroup of the symmetric group of the set on which $G$ acts. Since said symmetric group has $n!$ elements, the size of $G$ is at most $n!$ as well.

Answer (score 2):

If $G$ acts on a set $X$ via an action $G \times X \to X, (g,x) \mapsto gx$, then the map $G \to \text{Sym}(X), g \to (x \mapsto gx)$ is a homomorphism of groups. It is not difficult to show that the action is faithful if and only if this homomorphism is injective. Finally, recall that for finite $X$ we have $|\text{Sym}(X)| = |X|!$.